# When did Wiktoria Narutowicz die?

Tags: poland, president, death, poland-lithuania

Is it possible to find when [Wiktoria ze Szczepkowskich](https://pl.rodovid.org/wk/Osoba:927465), mother of [Gabriel Narutowicz](https://pl.rodovid.org/wk/Osoba:503799) ([his Wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Narutowicz)) died?

I found [rodovid.org](https://pl.rodovid.org/wk/Osoba:927465) but there is no date of death.

I also checked in Gabriel Narutowicz biography by Tadeusz Hołówko but there is nothing about date of death of Wiktoria Narutowicz (Szczepkowska).

Comment: According to [this site](https://kielakowie.com/familygroup.php?familyID=F30740&tree=tree381), the date is unknown, but that's the only site with any info I could find. Perhaps those who voted to close as 'too basic' could clarify?

Comment: I'd prefer not to close a question with an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Searching online for Wiktoria's married name seems to be drawing surprisingly few results, and all of them blanks. Like ["Died after 1865 after age 21 [location unknown]"](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Szczepkowska-1)…

However, she is listed 'properly' at geni.com (and some paywalled sites for the same topic), under her maiden name;
although using 'V' and missing a 't' in her first name, *and* an 'alternative spelling' for the last name…:

> [Vicoria Shepovska](https://www.geni.com/people/Vicoria-Narutavi%C4%8Dien%C4%97/6000000006882790083)
> Lithuanian: Viktorija Narutavičienė (Ščepauskaitė), Polish: Wiktoria Narutowicz (Szczepowska)
> Birthdate:  February 23, 1832
> Birthplace: Renavas, Mažeikiai District / Telšiai County, Lithuania, Russian Empire
> Death:  June 01, 1908 (76)
> Immediate Family:
> Daughter of Ipolit Szczepkowski and Elena Szczepkowska
> Wife of Jan Stanislaus Narutovich
> Mother of Stanisław Narutowicz h. wł. and Gabriel Narutowicz, Prezydent RP

Note that in other Baltic languages her name would spell 'Viktorija Ščepovskaitė-Narutavičienė' or 'Viktorijas Narutaviča, dzimušas Ščepkovskas' on the respective Wikipedia pages (for Gabriel). Such idiosyncracies need to be accounted for when researching her details further, since for example Gabriel's brother [Stanisław Narutowicz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Narutowicz) did not make much of a career in Poland under that name, but in Lithuania as Stanislovas Narutavičius. This family was rather 'international'…

Comment: That's most probably correct - https://zw.lt/opinie/gabriel-narutowicz-litewski-polak-prezydent-polski-skonczylby-150-lat/ says the same: `W tym samym, 1908 r. w Telszach (lit. Telšiai) zmarła matka Gabriela.`